# Storing page data in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store webpage data for a website build in PHP so that I can access it for components like navigation and breadcrumbs.

At the moment I've got an array in my config file which has each page's name, path and parent data, but I realise this is almost certainly wrong.

How should this data be optimally stored? I thought about a MySQL table but it seems like overkill for a small site.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your config file approach, at least in principle.

Comment: is the data you're looking to persist static or dynamic? if it is static and related to site configuration, then you can store it in file, especially if you are designing a small and simple web site. However, if you got to manage users and dynamic data, then the database is mandatory.

Comment: It'd be a static website. No users or dynamic data, though that may change in future.